# Custom TextBox Control About OnPaint Method

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

This probably is an embarrassing question but I have created a custom textbox which has a red border using help from MSDN website.

I understand I have inherited from the UserControl class and overridden its OnPaint() method.

Can someone tell me where the OnPaint() method is being called as I can't see it in the code.

Here is the code -

```
namespace CustomTextBox
{
  public partial class BorderTextBox : UserControl
  {
    private TextBox textBox;
    private Color myColor = Color.Red;
    public BorderTextBox()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.textBox = new TextBox();
      this.DoubleBuffered = true;
      this.Padding = new Padding(2);
      this.textBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
      this.textBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
      this.Controls.Add(this.textBox);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
      base.OnPaint(e);
      Pen borderPen = new Pen(myColor);
      e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(borderPen,
          new Rectangle(0, 0, this.ClientSize.Width - 1, this.ClientSize.Height - 1));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry about the formatting not sure why that's happened.

Comment: You need to override the OnPaint()method to achieve this. I would recommend looking into this as this will be exactly what you would need.